# Restore database

Tags: postgresql

I want to restore a database in PostgreSQL but it can't. I have replaced `pg_restore` in bin folder but it's still not working. The message is :

```
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.12) in file header
```

Comment: this might be able to help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599696/use-pg-restore-to-restore-from-a-newer-version-of-postgresql/4599831#4599831

Comment: put your original (newer) `pg_restore` back and do `pg_restore --help` -- look for a `-i` option.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by upgrading postgresql from 8.X to 9.2.4. If you're using brew on Mac OS-X, use -

```
brew upgrade postgresql
```

Once this is done, just make sure your new postgres installation is at the top of your path. It'll look something like (depending on the version installation path) -

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the archive was created with a version newer than the pg_restore you are using can support.  The best way to fix this is to install a newer version of pg_restore.  Note that this limitation has more recently gone away.  I can use pg_restore from 9.1 against a 9.2 custom dump file for example.